# How to auto adjust the height of fixed footer at bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the desired result as mentioned in the uploaded picture. Here is the explanation of both the views:

**I always want the margin between the area A and area C as 20px. If the screen size changes, area C should fill up the gap (as shown in View 2) keeping the margin always 20px between area A and area C.** Currently, whenever screen size changes the gap between area A and area C increase or decrease which I don't want rather it should be filled by area C.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Learn</title>
    <link href = "styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <div class="boxA">
        <h2>A</h2>
        <div class="boxD"><h2>D</h2></div>
        <div class="boxD"><h2>D</h2></div> 
      </div>
      <div class="boxB">
        <h2>B</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="boxC">
        <h2>C</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
}
body, h2{
  margin: 0;
}

.boxA{
  width: 500px;
  height: 580px;
  background-color: #006400;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.boxB{
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.boxC{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.boxD{
  width:220px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left:20px;
  float:left;
}
```

**Note: I want to achieve this just by CSS. No Javascript.**

[image]

Comment: I absolutely fail to understand why this question got upvotes. To me it looks like a typical *work-for-me-for-free-because-i-m-too-lazy-to-(re)search* question. Most likely, nobody except the asker will benefit from the answer. I'd love if anyone who upvoted would explain their reasoning, as the upvote label clearly states: "*This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear*". Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flexbox` property comes in handy here. Read more about it at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) or at [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

> The **CSS3 Flexible Box**, or **flexbox**, is a layout mode providing for the
>   arrangement of elements on a page such that the elements behave
>   predictably when the page layout must accommodate different screen
>   sizes and different display devices. For many applications, the
>   flexible box model provides an improvement over the block model in
>   that it does not use floats, nor do the flex container's margins
>   collapse with the margins of its contents.

I reproduced the images you provided and set the ratio of the content versus the footer to 4:1 (or 80% to 20% in values). Please take a look at the code below and be sure to check out the full screen version to see it working properly, or check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14escdv5/). You can change the values to your needs, but the main part is this:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

It gets repeated in various child element to fit the needs.

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
}

.green {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 60%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.box {
  width: calc(50% - 50px);
  margin: 20px;
  background: darkgreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.blue {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 30%;
  max-height: 50%;
  background: blue;
}

.footer {
  height: 20%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="green">
      a
      <div class="box">d</div>
      <div class="box">d</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="blue">
    b
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    c
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you for coming up with the solution though it's not giving me the desired result. The height of area C is not changing with the screen size and I don't want area B to be in the same line always.

Comment: You can adjust the height of area C with media queries, same goes for area B. It all depends on your browser width. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: It is actually working fine as required. Looked it incorrectly. Thanks!